# Forcing page reload from Vaadin portlet

Tags: portlet, reload, vaadin

Is there an easy way to force the entire page to reload from Vaadin? I have a portlet which affects the header value displayed which is pulled from IBM WebSphere's dynamic cache in a separate JSP.

I am porting over an old JSF portlet to Vaadin which depending on page reloads between actions to reflect the new value in the header template. So now I need to force the entire page (not just the portlet) to reload to make it appear that the action took effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can reload the hosting web page with JavaScript:

```
getMainWindow().executeJavaScript("window.location.reload();");
```

I think this should also do the trick in a portal.

Comment: Thanks that works however it can affect other porlets on the page. For example another JSF portlet on the page which performs a postback and then using doing something on the Vaadin porlet which causes the reload to occur will result in two issues: 1) very ugly IE/Firefox warning message "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action..." and 2) causes the JSF portlet to serialize (JSF specific issue I'm guessing) and blow up due to transient variables. I can fix the transient problem but the #1 is still an issue.

Comment: Yes, this is "entire page to reload". If you want only part of the portlets to be loaded, you have to build the support into those portlets (or use some generic server specific extension for this). For a Vaadin application portlet refresh you can call the vaadin.forceSync() JavaScript method.

Comment: Note that the Vaadin 7 way to force a full page reload through JavaScript would be `getUI().getPage().getJavaScript().execute("window.location.reload();");`